# Why is the animation not playing?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, render, gltf

I receive no errors and the animation seems to actually play if i try console.log
but nothing happens on the screen.

```
  //gltf-object
   const loader = new GLTFLoader();
   loader.load('stegosaurs_SStenops.glb', (gltf) => {
   gltf.scene.position.set(0, 40, 130);
   scene.add(gltf.scene);
  // gltf-animation;
   let clips = gltf.animations;
   let mixer = new AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
  const clip = AnimationClip.findByName( clips, 'walk1' );
  const action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
  action.play();
  let clock = new Clock();
  } );
```

and in the renderloop

```
  function update () {
    mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
  }
```

### Full Code

```js
//.................SETUP................//
import {
  WebGLRenderer,
  PerspectiveCamera,
  Scene,
  BoxGeometry,
  MeshBasicMaterial,
  Mesh,
  Group,
  PlaneGeometry,
  AxesHelper,
  GridHelper,
  DoubleSide,
  DirectionalLight,
  AmbientLight,
  MeshStandardMaterial,
  DirectionalLightHelper,
  Fog,
  TextureLoader,
  CubeTextureLoader,
  SphereGeometry,
  CameraHelper,
  Color,
  ShaderMaterial,
  SphereBufferGeometry,
  BackSide,
  Raycaster,
  Vector2,
  NumberKeyframeTrack,
  AnimationClip,
  AnimationMixer,
  OrthographicCamera,
  PointsMaterial,
  Points,
  MeshPhongMaterial,
  FogExp2,
  Vector3,
  Box3,
  Sphere,
  Plane,
  BooleanKeyframeTrack,
  Ray,
  Clock,
  SkeletonHelper,
  PolarGridHelper,
  BoxHelper,
  Line,
  BufferGeometry,
} from './three.module.js';
//import { MapControls, OrbitControls } from './q.js';
import vShader from './vertex.glsl.js';
import fShader from './fragment.glsl.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from './GLTFLoader.js';
//................PROGRAM...............//
// callable functions
 //Requests
   // const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   // request.open("Post", "https://discoverthreejs.com/book/first-steps/world-app/");
   // request.send();
   // request.onload = () => {console.log(request)}
// variables
var renderer, camera, scene, light, light1, geometry, material, mesh;
// renderer
renderer = new WebGLRenderer({canvas:
document.getElementById('Canvas'), antialias: true, alfa: true});
//alfa: true gör att tomma pixlar i canvasen visar underliggande html-innehåll så att om man exempelvis skulle ha en bild under ett tomt canvas-element så kan man ändå se bilden. 
//renderer.setClearColor(0x555555);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
// camera
camera = new PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 0.1, 6000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 150);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
// orthographic camera
// OrthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 1000);
// OrthographicCamera.position.set(0, 0, 0,);// 
//controls
  //var orbitcontrol = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
//scene
scene = new Scene();
//lights
var ambientlight = new AmbientLight(0x333333, 0.2);
scene.add(ambientlight);
var sun = new DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.4);
sun.castShadow = true;
scene.add(sun);
sun.position.set(0, 40, 0);
//shadow map
sun.shadow.camera.top = 25;
sun.shadow.camera.bottom = - 25;
sun.shadow.camera.left = - 25;
sun.shadow.camera.right = 25;
sun.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
sun.shadow.camera.far = 100;
//fog
//scene.fog = new Fog(0xffffff, 0, 200); 
//helpers
var gridhelper = new GridHelper(10, 10);
scene.add(gridhelper);
var axishelper = new AxesHelper(3);
scene.add(axishelper);
var directionallighthelper = new DirectionalLightHelper(sun, 10, 0xff0000);
scene.add(directionallighthelper);
scene.add( new CameraHelper( sun.shadow.camera ) );
const polarGridHelper = new PolarGridHelper( 200, 16, 8, 64, 0x0000ff, 0x808080 );
polarGridHelper.position.set(0, 100, 0);
scene.add( polarGridHelper );
//material loaders
var bildimport = new TextureLoader().load('a.jpg');
var bildimport2 = new TextureLoader().load('träd.jpg');
var textureLoader = new TextureLoader();
//scene.background = textureLoader.load('a.jpg');
//object
let model, mixer, idleAction, walkAction, runAction, actions;
  //gltf-object
   const loader = new GLTFLoader();
   loader.load('stegosaurs_SStenops.glb', (gltf) => {
   gltf.scene.position.set(0, 40, 130);
   gltf.scene.visible = true;
   model = gltf.scene;
   scene.add(model);
   let skeleton = new SkeletonHelper(model)
   scene.add( skeleton );
   // gltf-animation
   let clips = gltf.animations;
   let mixer = new AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
   const clip = AnimationClip.findByName( clips, 'walk1' );
   const action = mixer.clipAction( clip );
   action.play();
   let clock = new Clock();
  } );
  
  //sky box
  let materialarray = [];
  let texture1 = new TextureLoader().load('träd.jpg'); //1
  let texture2 = new TextureLoader().load('träd.jpg'); //2
  let texture3 = new TextureLoader().load('träd.jpg'); //3
  let texture4 = new TextureLoader().load('träd.jpg'); //4
  let texture5 = new TextureLoader().load('träd.jpg'); //5
  let texture6 = new TextureLoader().load('träd.jpg'); //6

  materialarray.push(new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture1})); //1
  materialarray.push(new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture2})); //2
  materialarray.push(new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture3})); //3
  materialarray.push(new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture4})); //4
  materialarray.push(new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture5})); //5
  materialarray.push(new MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture6})); //6

for(let i=0; i<6; i++){
  materialarray[i].side = BackSide;
}
  let skyboxGeometry = new BoxGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000);
  let skybox = new Mesh(skyboxGeometry, materialarray);
  scene.add(skybox);
  //shader object
  var geometryShader = new SphereGeometry(1, 50, 50)
  var materialShader = new ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: vShader,
    fragmentShader: fShader,
  }) 
  var meshShader = new Mesh(geometryShader, materialShader);
  scene.add(meshShader);
//sphere
var randomcolor1 = new Color().setRGB(Math.random() * 16, Math.random() * 16, Math.random() * 16);
var geometrySphere = new SphereGeometry(10, 15);
var materialSphere = new MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: randomcolor1,
  flatShading: true,
  metalness: 1,
  roughness: 1,
  //transparent: true,
  //opacity: 0.9, // nota bene, transparent has to be true for this to work
  name: 'Sphere',
  //wireframe: true,
});
var meshSphere = new Mesh(geometrySphere, materialSphere);
scene.add(meshSphere);
meshSphere.position.set(0, 20, 0)
meshSphere.receiveShadow = true;
meshSphere.castShadow = true;
//cube
geometry = new BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var alt_material = [
new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport2}),
new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport}),
new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport2}),
new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport}),
new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport2}),
new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport}),
];
material = new MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xff00ff,
  map: bildimport2,
});
mesh = new Mesh(geometry, alt_material);
mesh.position.set(0, 40, 0);
mesh.castShadow = true;
scene.add(mesh);
//plane
var randomcolor2 = new Color().setRGB(Math.random() * 16, Math.random() * 16, Math.random() * 16);
var geometry2 = new PlaneGeometry(400, 400); 
var material2 = new MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: randomcolor2,
  map: bildimport,
  side: DoubleSide,  
  name: 'Plane',
});
var mesh2 = new Mesh(geometry2, material2);
mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(mesh2);
mesh2.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
//objects
let SubdividedPlane = new Mesh(
  new PlaneGeometry(40, 40),
  new MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xf034f3,
    //visible: false,
    side: DoubleSide,
    name: 'SubdividedPlane',
  })  
);
SubdividedPlane.position.set(0, 1, 40); //0, 50, 0
  SubdividedPlane.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
scene.add(SubdividedPlane);
let grid = new GridHelper(40, 20); // 20, 20
grid.position.set(0, 1, 40);

scene.add(grid);

let SubPlane = new Mesh(new PlaneGeometry(2, 2), new MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'black', side: DoubleSide})); // 1, 1
SubPlane.position.set(0.5, 1, 40.5);  // 0.5, 50, 0.5
SubPlane.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
scene.add(SubPlane);
    // Event listener for extracting mousclick to imediatly restore camera direction
    window.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
      var a = 0;
      camera.lookAt(a, a, a);
    })
    // Event listener to behold proportions whene resize 
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  var widthResize = window.innerWidth;
  var heightResize = window.innerHeight;
  renderer.setSize(widthResize, heightResize);
  camera.aspect = widthResize/heightResize;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix;
});
   // Event listener to activate function on keypress
   // blockboxes
let boxSphere = new Box3().setFromObject(meshSphere);
console.log(boxSphere.min.x, boxSphere.max.x);
let boxPlane = new Box3().setFromObject(mesh2);
console.log(boxPlane)
   //
   let latest_botton_pressed_variable;
   //
     // right (r)
     let off_switch_1 = false;
   var cameraChangeRight = 0
   window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
     if(e.code === "KeyR"){
      if(latest_botton_pressed_variable == 1 && off_switch_1 == true){cameraChangeRight += 0} else {cameraChangeRight += 10};
      cameraChangeRight += 10;
      latest_botton_pressed_variable = 1
    };
   });
       // left (l)
       let off_switch_2 = false;
   var cameraChangeLeft = 0
   window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
     console.log(e.code);
     if(e.code === "KeyL"){
      if(latest_botton_pressed_variable == 2 && off_switch_2 == true){cameraChangeLeft += 0} else {cameraChangeLeft += 10};
      latest_botton_pressed_variable = 2;
    }
   });
       // upp (u)
       let off_switch_3 = false;
   var cameraChangeUpp = 0
   window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
     console.log(e.code);
     if(e.code === "KeyU"){
      if(latest_botton_pressed_variable == 3 && off_switch_3 == true){cameraChangeUpp += 0} else {cameraChangeUpp += 10};
      latest_botton_pressed_variable = 3;
    }
   });
       // down (d)
       let off_switch_4 = false;
   var cameraChangeDown = 0
   window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
     console.log(e.code);
     if(e.code === "KeyD"){
       if(latest_botton_pressed_variable == 4 && off_switch_4 == true){cameraChangeDown += 0} else {cameraChangeDown += 10};
      latest_botton_pressed_variable = 4;
    }
   });
       // forward (f)
       let off_switch_5 = false;
       var cameraChangeForward = 0
       window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
         console.log(e.code);
         if(e.code === "KeyF"){
          if(latest_botton_pressed_variable == 5 && off_switch_5 == true){cameraChangeForward += 0} else {cameraChangeForward -=10};
          latest_botton_pressed_variable = 5;
        }
       });
       // backward (b)
       let off_switch_6 = false;
       var cameraChangeBackward = 0
       window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
         console.log(e.code);
         if(e.code === "KeyB"){
          if(latest_botton_pressed_variable == 6 && off_switch_6 == true){cameraChangeBackward += 0} else {cameraChangeBackward -= 10};
          latest_botton_pressed_variable = 6;
        }
       });
     // Camera direction manouvering keyss
     // right (ArrowRight)
   var cameraChangeRight2 = 0
   window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
     console.log(e.code);
     if(e.code === "KeyS"){
      cameraChangeRight2 += 10;
      console.log(cameraChangeRight2)
    }
   });
       // left (ArrowLeft)
   var cameraChangeLeft2 = 0
   window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
     console.log(e.code);
     if(e.code === "KeyA"){
      cameraChangeLeft2 += 10;
      console.log(cameraChangeLeft2);
    }
   });
       // upp (ArrowUp)
   var cameraChangeUpp2 = 0
   window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
     console.log(e.code);
     if(e.code === "KeyX"){
      cameraChangeUpp2 += 10;
      console.log(cameraChangeUpp2);
    }
   });
       // down (ArrowDown)
   var cameraChangeDown2 = 0
   window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
     console.log(e.code);
     if(e.code === "KeyZ"){
      cameraChangeDown2 += 10;
      console.log(cameraChangeDown2)
    }
   });
//raycaster
var raycaster = new Raycaster();
var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  INTERSECTED;
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
  // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
  //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
  var mouse = new Vector2();
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  var raycaster = new Raycaster();
  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
  let objects = [];
  objects.push(meshSphere, mesh, mesh2, meshShader, SubdividedPlane, SubPlane);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects); 
  
  if(intersects.length > 0) {
       console.log(intersects[0].object.material)
    //console.log(intersects[0].object.material.name)
    switch(intersects[0].object.material.name){
      case 'Sphere':
        window.open("./entry.html");
        break;
      case 'Plane':
        starfunction();
        break;
      case 'SubdividedPlane':
        console.log(intersects[0].point); 
        let selectedPositionFloor = new Vector3().copy(intersects[0].point).floor();
        if(selectedPositionFloor.x % 2 == 0){selectedPositionFloor.x +=1}else{console.log("jämmn koordinat_(X)")};
        if(selectedPositionFloor.z % 2 == 0){selectedPositionFloor.z +=1}else{console.log("jämnt koordinat_(Z)")};
        SubPlane.position.set(selectedPositionFloor.x, 1, selectedPositionFloor.z);
        // if (one of four boxes in singelgridfield){execute}
        if((SubPlane.position.x == 1 || 2) && (SubPlane.position.z == 40 ||41)){console.log("1:1")};
        if((SubPlane.position.x == 3 || 4) && (SubPlane.position.z == 40 ||41)){console.log("2:1")};
        console.log("----------",SubPlane.position,"----------")
        break;
      default:
        console.log("default switch-statement - (intersects)")
      }; 
}};
document.addEventListener( 'click', onDocumentMouseDown, false );   
// CSS - animations 
function starfunction(){
  let stjärnhimmel = document.getElementById("stjärnhimmel");
  if(stjärnhimmel.style.opacity == "0"){
    stjärnhimmel.style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    stjärnhimmel.style.opacity = "0";
  }
}
 //function starfunction(){document.getElementById("stjärnhimmel").style.opacity = "1"};
//renderer loop 
let CameraBlockShapesDetectorFrontBorder;
let CameraBlockShapesDetectorBackBorder;
let CameraBlockShapesDetectorBox;
let meshSphereBoundingBox = new Sphere(meshSphere.position, 10);


requestAnimationFrame(render);
//render variables
var i = 0;
var increase_of_i = 0.01;
var x = 0;
var y = 50;
var z = 150;
var increase_of_z = 0.125;
let clock = new Clock();
function render() {  
  ////////////////////
  
  
  let mixerUpdateDelta = clock.getDelta();
  mixer.update( mixerUpdateDelta );
  
  
  
  ////////////////////
  
  
  
  
 // keyboard camera position maneuvering
 function updateCameraChange(){
  //console.log(camera.position, CameraBlockShapesDetectorFrontBorder);
camera.position.set(x + cameraChangeRight - cameraChangeLeft, y + cameraChangeUpp - cameraChangeDown, z + cameraChangeForward - cameraChangeBackward)};
CameraBlockShapesDetectorFrontBorder = new Vector3(camera.position.x +10, camera.position.y + 10, camera.position.z + 10);
CameraBlockShapesDetectorBackBorder = new Vector3(camera.position.x - 10, camera.position.y -10, camera.position.z -10);
CameraBlockShapesDetectorBox = new Box3(CameraBlockShapesDetectorBackBorder, CameraBlockShapesDetectorFrontBorder);
if(CameraBlockShapesDetectorBox.intersectsSphere(meshSphereBoundingBox)){
//console.log("Collision against meshSphereBoundingBox!");
switch(latest_botton_pressed_variable){
  case 1:
    off_switch_1 = true;
    break;
  case 2:
    off_switch_2 = true;
    break;
  case 3:
    off_switch_3 = true;
    break;
  case 4:
    off_switch_4 = true;
    break;  
  case 5:
    off_switch_5 = true;
    break;
  case 6:
    off_switch_6 = true;
    break;
  default:
    console.log("default in switch-statement - (latest_botton_pressed");
}
};
if(CameraBlockShapesDetectorBox.intersectsBox(boxPlane)){
  switch(latest_botton_pressed_variable){
    case 1:
      off_switch_1 = true;
      break;
    case 2:
      off_switch_2 = true;
      break;
    case 3:
      off_switch_3 = true;
      break;
    case 4:
      off_switch_4 = true;
      break;  
    case 5:
      off_switch_5 = true;
      break;
    case 6:
      off_switch_6 = true;
      break;
    default:
      console.log("default in switch-statement - (latest_botton_pressed");
  }
  //console.log("Collision against PlaneBoundingBox!");
};
if(CameraBlockShapesDetectorBox.intersectsBox(boxPlane) == false && CameraBlockShapesDetectorBox.intersectsSphere(meshSphereBoundingBox) == false){
  off_switch_1 = off_switch_2 = off_switch_3 = off_switch_4 = off_switch_5 = off_switch_6 = false;
}
updateCameraChange();
 // keyboard camera direction manuvering 
function updateCameraDirection(){
  camera.lookAt(0 + cameraChangeRight2 - cameraChangeLeft2, 0 + cameraChangeUpp2 - cameraChangeDown2);
}
updateCameraDirection();

meshSphere.rotation.y += 0.01;
meshSphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
meshSphere.rotation.z += 0.01;
i += increase_of_i;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
#stjärnhimmel{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
}
#stjärnhimmel span{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #4fc3dc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #4fc3dc44,
    0 0 50px #4fc3dc,
    0 0 100px #4fc3dc;
    margin: 0 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: stjärnhimmel 15s infinite;
    animation-duration: calc(90s/var(--i));
}
@keyframes stjärnhimmel{
    0%{transform: translateY(100vh) scale(0.5);}
    100%{transform: translateY(-10vh) scale(1);}
}
#stjärnhimmel span:nth-child(even){
    background: #ff2d75;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #ff2d7544,
    0 0 50px #ff2d75,
    0 0 100px #ff2d75;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="3D_Canvas.css">
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="stjärnhimmel">
      <span style="--i:11"></span>
      <span style="--i:12"></span>
      <span style="--i:24"></span>
      <span style="--i:14"></span>
      <span style="--i:23"></span>
      <span style="--i:18"></span>
      <span style="--i:16"></span>
      <span style="--i:19"></span>
      <span style="--i:20"></span>
      <span style="--i:22"></span>
      <span style="--i:25"></span>
      <span style="--i:18"></span>
      <span style="--i:21"></span>
      <span style="--i:15"></span>
      <span style="--i:13"></span>
      <span style="--i:26"></span>
      <span style="--i:17"></span>
      <span style="--i:13"></span>
      <span style="--i:28"></span>
      <span style="--i:11"></span>
      <span style="--i:12"></span>
      <span style="--i:24"></span>
      <span style="--i:14"></span>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your model? Can you share the gltf model?

Comment: Defining the instance of `Clock` in the `onLoad()` callback does not seem right.

Comment: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/stylized-stegosaurs-game-model-3d-model-1937889

Comment: Removed it from the onload() and placed it in the global scope, still something is wrong though.

Comment: Can you please log the `clip` object into your browser console and make sure it isn't `null`?

Comment: It says it's something: AnimationClip {name: 'walk1', tracks: Array(159), duration: 1.6666666269302368, blendMode: 2500, uuid: 'c3eb309e-4bc0-4450-9fdb-2e41cbbcc177'}

Comment: Does your `update()` function also contain code to re-render on each frame, calling `renderer.render(scene, camera)`? I don't see it above, and that would be a problem if it's not doing so.

Comment: The function itself is located in the render loop requestinq renderer.render (scen, camera)

Comment: Added a snippet so you can see @DonMcCurdy

Comment: I've moved the snippet into the question, it will get deleted when posted as an "answer" on Stack Overflow. Anyway — do you see any errors in your JavaScript console? It doesn't appear to me that this code will run. For one thing, the 'mixer' variable is defined only within a callback, and won't be accessible in the render function.